# show graphical reprsentaion of neo4j json results

Tags: javascript, neo4j

I am trying to display the json results from neo4j  to graphical representaion using javascript.Below is my code

```
   <html>

   <body>
   <div class="alchemy" id="alchemy"></div>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.graphalchemist.com/alchemy.min.css" />
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alchemyjs/0.4.2/alchemy.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

    var config = {
        dataSource: {
            "comment": "Charlize Theron's 'ego' network as GraphJSON",
            "nodes": [
              {
                  "caption": "Screen Actors Guild Award for Outstanding Performance by a Female Actor in a Miniseries or Television Movie",
                  "type": "award",
                  "id": 595472
              },
                {
                    "caption": "Children of the Corn III: Urban Harvest",
                    "type": "movie",
                    "id": 626470
                 },
                {
                     "caption": "Sleepwalking",
                        "type": "movie",
                     "id": 795744
                },

            ],
            "edges": [
               {
                   "source": 314003,
                   "target": 621675,
                   "caption": "ACTED_IN"
               },
                {
                    "source": 314003,
                    "target": 818608,
                    "caption": "ACTED_IN"
                },
                {
                     "source": 314003,
                        "target": 601849,
                    "caption": "NOMINATED"
                },
            ]
        }
    };

    alchemy = new Alchemy(config)
</script>
```

I am not getting the output and the error is :d3 is not defined and d is not a function

If anyone can help please suggest how to display the result in graph format

Comment: Related: https://github.com/GraphAlchemist/Alchemy/issues/574

Comment: Bad news: https://github.com/GraphAlchemist/Alchemy/issues/573

Comment: Is there any alternative solution?

Comment: Maybe https://www.graphdracula.net/showcase/

Comment: Have a look at the [Neo4J resource page for visualization](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/).